# Mouse movement affects HDMI screen output

Tags: mouse, touchpad, screen, hdmi, radeon

weird one this, still not certain if it's hardware or O/S related.

This is about a Dell Inspiron Core i5 with Radeon graphics, running Ubuntu 18.04.

Yesterday, I added a second monitor, via a HDMI to DVI digital cable. Ran absolutely fine, everything good for most of a day's work.

Today, after a few minutes working, the remote screen started flickering off and on.  Completely dark for about half a second, then back on.  No other symptoms.  Checked all cables, then realised that it was movement of the (wireless) mouse that caused the off/on, and I thought 'RF interference'...

So I switched it for a cable mouse; problem remained.  Tried moving the mouse with the tracker pad, still the same.  I haven't done any updates to Ubuntu since I installed it a month ago, although I guess something might have auto-updated(?).

Can't understand why it didn't happen when I first added the screen.  All suggestions gratefully received.

Many thanks,

John M

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a full answer, but it may give a clue.  The laptop is my wife's; she had, somehow, sitting behind her browser session, multiple iterations of the calculator app. loaded.  No idea how; she swears (and I believe her) that she hasn't even used the calculator this morning (is it possible to accidentally launch it with a keystroke combination?), and she's pretty computer-literate.

Anyway, I closed the calculator (lost count of the times I had to do it, because you generally don't start counting when you click to close a program), rebooted, problem gone away.  OK, yes, should have rebooted as the first resort, but my initial instinct was to work out what was wrong in case it happened again.

There you go; thanks for reading, hope it doesn't happen to you.

Cheers